# What does すきすき mean here?

Tags: translation

https://ameblo.jp/kyawahara1026/entry-12360353230.html

> なみポリス出動
>   あみちゃんスキスキ罪

Is this supposed to be "好き好き"? I thought that was supposed to すきずき though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

***'s' vs. 'z'***

「好き好き」 has two completely different meanings depending on how the ***second*** 「好き」 is read.

1. When read 「すき**ず**き」, it is a noun meaning "***a matter of taste***".  This is a "dictionary" word; therefore, it is written as 「好き好き」 99% of the time.

The well-known saying "There is no accounting for tastes." is thus translated to 「蓼{たで}食{く}う虫{むし}も好{す}き好{ず}き」 nearly everytime.

2. When read 「すきすき」, it is just 「好き」 **said twice for emphasis**.  You like/love something/someone **very much**.  Since this is ***not*** a dictionary word, it is written the way the writer wants to -- 「好き好き」、「すきすき」 or 「スキスキ」.

In the phrase 「あみちゃんスキスキ罪{ざい}」, 「スキスキ」 is clearly the second usage above.  It would mean something along the lines of:

***"Crime of loving Ami-chan excessively"***

Comment: I wonder, is there any semantic overlap between すきすき and "like-like"?  In English, the first "like" is often emphasized with tone of voice, or in writing, sometimes with italics, as "_like_-like".  The sense is that you "like" them, but also **really** like them.  As in, not just friendly affection.